# change a number to a variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, assign

i need to change a number to a variable named "gender" so later in my "if statements" i can say something like "If Male button is pressed then Gender = 24". so i need to know how write a variable that looks something like Gender = 24 (it will change in the if statement). ive been reading around and i can't really figure out where i can assign variables.

[Click here for an example](http://s3.postimg.org/9o553bffn/Screen_Shot_2014_04_03_at_3_41_56_PM.png)

that top line of code will look like `float answer = (Gender + [shoeSize.text floatValue])/3;` when i figure out how to use the variables.

i hope you can help me! (also, sorry for my incompetence with xcode! im kinda new)

Comment: I apologize but what is the question?

Comment: why don't you add the code as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're writing your code in `UIViewController`. Just declare an `@property NSInteger gender` in the .h file, and access the variable as `self.gender` and set it with `self.gender = 24`.

Comment: irrelvant whether what the type of the owner of the method is. every type of class can have properties, not only the inheritances of the `UIViewController`.